# Getting two lists using Xpath that are both contained in the same container

Tags: xpath, scrapy

In the code sample below I'm looking to extract, using Xpath inside of Scrapy, first from list 1 and then from list 2.  Some items may be linked out while others are just items in the list.  What I need is two strings (or lists) one for List 1 and one for List 2

```html
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12 no-padding-xs">
   <h3 class="text-primary gutter-xs">List 1</h3>
   <div class="well well-sm">
    <a href="/miniature.htm">Miniature</a>, <a href="/mustang.htm">Mustang</a>, <a href="/paintpony.htm">Paint Pony</a>, <a href="https://www.equinenow.com/browse-brf-pi">Pinto</a>, <a href="/pony.htm">Pony</a>, <a href="/poa.htm">POA</a>, <a href="/quarterpony.htm">Quarter Pony</a>, <a href="/shetlandpony.htm">Shetland Pony</a>, <a href="/spanishmustang.htm">Spanish Mustang</a>
   </div>
   <h3 class="text-primary gutter-xs">List 2</h3>
   <div class="well well-sm">
    <a href="/allaroundfarms.htm">All Around</a>, <a href="/drivingfarms.htm">Driving</a>, <a href="/halterfarms.htm">Halter</a>, <a href="/lessonfarms.htm">Lesson</a>, <a href="/naturalhorsemanshipfarms.htm">Natural Horsemanship</a>, <a href="/showfarms.htm">Show</a>, Trail Riding, <a href="/westernpleasurefarms.htm">Western Pleasure</a>, Western Riding, <a href="/youthfarms.htm">Youth</a>, Champion Trainer, POA Ponies for Sale, Newaygo County, Horse Boarding, Equestrian Coaching, Michigan, Riding Lessons, Horse Lea
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure that I understood you properly, but you can try:

```
from w3lib.html import remove_tags

for list_text in ['List 1', 'List 2']:
    div_data = response.xpath('//h3[text()="{}"]/following-sibling::div[1]'.format(list_text)).get()
    if not div_data:
         continue
    print [remove_tags(i).strip() for i in div_data.split(',')]
```

Or if you want just strings:

```
for list_text in ['List 1', 'List 2']:
    div_data = response.xpath('//h3[text()="{}"]/following-sibling::div[1]'.format(list_text)).get()
    if not div_data:
         continue
    print remove_tags(div_data)
```